# L'Hôpital's rule: number of iterations...

Tags: calculus, infinity

I have this exercise :

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} {(\ln x)^9\over x} $$

Now, I know I must use the L'Hôpital's rule to solve this one, until I reach:

somthing*$ 1/x^2 $ ,because each time I get infinity/infinity, I am allowed to use L'Hospital's rule.

My question is: Is there any shortcut to solve such problems?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Yes there is: if you know the general theorem that for any $\alpha,\beta >0$, $\;(\ln x)^\alpha=o(x^\beta)$.

Comment: Just don't use L'Hospital!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is somewhat informal and verbose, but easily made rigorous.

Note that the fraction is eventually monotonically decreasing*. This means that instead of $x$ we can take *any sequence* $a_n$ which goes to $\infty$ as $n$ increases, and the limit will be the same as in the continuous case.

Set $a_n=e^{2^n}$, and note what happens between $\frac{(\ln a_n)^9}{a_n}$ and $\frac{(\ln a_{n+1})^9}{a_{n+1}}$:

- The numerator is multiplied by $2^9=512$
- The denominator is squared, i.e. multiplied with itself

It doesn't take long to reach a point where this means the entire expression is multiplied by, say, something smaller than $\frac12$, and it keeps getting multiplied by smaller and smaller numbers each time we increase $n$ by $1$. From that point on we move quickly towards $0$.

* We have
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{(\ln x)^9}{x}=\frac{9(\ln x)^8\cdot\frac1x\cdot x-(\ln x)^9}{x^2}\\
=\frac{(\ln x)^8}{x^2}(9-\ln x)
$$
and we see that for all $x>e^9$, this is negative.

Comment: It is a false assertion that if $f, g : (1, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ are increasing and $\displaystyle q = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(a_n)}{g(a_n)}$ exists for some $a_n \to \infty$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = q$.

Comment: @Adayah You're right. We need that the fraction as a whole is monotonic. It has been fixed.

Answer (score 14):

I wouldn't invoke L'Hôpital's rule here.

Knowing that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x} = 0$, you get

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x^{1/9}}{x^{1/9}} = 0 = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^{1/9}}$.

You can then elevate at the 9th power as $x \mapsto x^9$ is continuous to get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} {(\ln x)^9\over x}=0$$

Comment: Can you prove $(ln x)/x\to0$ without L'Hospital's Rule?  On the other hand, one application is definitely better than 9.

Comment: @Teepeemm - Everything that can be proved by L'Hopital's rule can also be proved without L'Hopital's rule. In this case a simple argument noting that $\ln x$ is the area under $1/t$ while $x$ is the area under $1$ can be used to prove that limit without recourse to L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @Teepeemm I understand that proving that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{x} =0$ is based in a way or another on l’Hôspital’s rule. However, I much prefer to go to basic arguments (use of derivative in particular) rather than using a *steam hammer* like l’Hôspital’s rule. Moreover, it provides a better understanding for students.

Answer (score 11):

You can prove $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (\ln x)^9 / x = 0$ without the L'Hôpital's rule.

Put $x = e^t$ then $x \to \infty \Leftrightarrow t \to \infty$ and
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\ln x)^9}{x} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^9}{e^t} = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: If it's not obvious how to solve the original limit without l'Hopital, I don't see how it's obvious how to solve this one.

Comment: >> Arthur
I think that $t^k / e^t \to 0$ is proved by the Taylor expansion immediately and $(\ln x)^k / x \to 0$ is not so.

Comment: @Arthur - Numer diffs down to $9!$.  Denom is idempotent under diff.  Now it is obvious - right?

Comment: So this answer makes sense once you make the substitution, but can you just _do_ that?  I mean, saying $x=e^t$ seems like something that requires assumptions that I know nothing about.

Comment: @user1717828 - You can set X as anything. So call it e^t and make things easier. Then t^9 is bigger than e^t when t^8 is bigger than e.

Comment: @ShyGuy Some might argue that solving limits through Taylor expansions and solving them through l'Hopital are two practically indistinguishable approaches; that it is, at least in an introductory calculus class, two names for the same technique (even though the exact theorems behind them may differ). I am one of those. I agree that if you want to use Taylor to the ninth degree / l'Hopital nine times, then your expression is a lot easier to work with. But if not, then I do not yet see how this answers the question.

Comment: @user1717828 You're right. Suppose we want to pass from a limit $L_x = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ to a limit $L_t = \displaystyle \lim_{t \to t_0} f(x(t))$ with a substitution $x = x(t)$. There are separate assumptions to pass in each direction: 1. If $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to t_0} x(t) = x_0$, then $L_t = L_x$ provided that $L_x$ exists. 2. If for each neighborhood $t_0 \in U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ there is a neighborhood $x_0 \in V \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $V \setminus \{ x_0 \} \subseteq x[U \setminus \{ t_0 \}]$, then $L_x = L_t$ provided that $L_t$ exists.

Comment: @user1717828 Also if $x(t)$ is invertible (like in this case $x(t) = e^t$ has an inverse $x^{-1}(s) = \ln s$), then the second condition can be replaced with $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to x_0} x^{-1}(s) = t_0$ (i.e. this condition also implies that $L_x = L_t$, provided that $L_t$ exists). So here since both $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} e^t = \infty$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to \infty} \ln s = \infty$, we know $L_x = L_t$ if whichever limit exists.

Comment: @Arthur
In fact, $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} t^k/e^t = 0$ is shown by more primitive argument, the following claim.

**Claim** $e^t \geq 1 + 1/1! t + \dots + 1/n! t^n$ for all $t \geq 0$ and $n \in \mathbf{N}$.

**Proof.** Let $f(t) = (1 + 1/1! t + \dots + 1/n! t^n) e^{-t}$. Then
\begin{align}
f'(t) &= (1 + 1/1!t + \dots + 1/(n-1)! t^{n-1})e^{-t} - (1 + 1/1! t + \dots + 1/n! t^n)e^{-t} \\
&= - 1/n! t^n e^{-t} \leq 0
\end{align}
So $f(t) \leq f(0) = 1$ and $1 + 1/1! t + \dots + 1/n! t^n \leq e^t$.

Answer (score 3):

Application of L'Hospital's Rule to $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x^{1/9}}$ reveals

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x^{1/9}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac1x}{\frac19x^{-8/9}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac9{x^{1/9}}=0$$

If $g(x)$ is the function $g(x)=x^9$, then

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log^9(x)}{x}&=\lim_{x\to \infty}g\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x^{1/9}}\right)\\\\
&=g\left(\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x^{1/9}}\right)\\\\
&=g(0)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

> **NOTE:**  If $f$ and $g$ satisfy the general conditions of L'Hospital's Rule, then application of L'Hospital's Rule to the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, with $g(x)\to \infty$, **does not require that the limit of the numerator approach $\infty$**.  In fact, the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ can even fail to exist.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** After applying l'Hopital's Rule a few times you'll notice that each application of the rule gives
$$C \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\ln x)^k}{x} = C \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{k (\ln x)^{k - 1}}{x}}{1} = C' \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\ln x)^{k - 1}}{x} ,$$ where we have absorbed the factor of $k$ into the new constant $C'$ (and that $C$ and $C'$ are both nonzero), and that the expression in the limit is identical except for the power of $\ln x$ that appears. (Of course, the computation assumes that the power rule applies, that is, that $k \neq 0$.)